# what are the really hard problems for NOCs

Tags: discussion

I want to ask the following question directed towards NOCs and network engineers.

What is the toughest problem you resolved? Be descriptive.

However, I'm not sure whether this would make the [faq](https://serverfault.com/faq).

Suggestions?

Comment: To add to what Iain's saying, you can of course pop into the commns room, the chat room for server fault and ask there. Are you collecting war stories, researching something or what are you working towards here? While Iain's right that this is off-topic on the main site, if there's something helpful we can do or another more suitable place we can refer you to depending on what you're after, we're happy to do that.

Comment: @RobM thanks for these suggestions. 

What is my purpose here?I am researching on how to go from programmer to infosec or network engineer. One motivation that underlies this is the need to not work *all* hrs. behind a desk. I also want to know if I can handle a NOC role and what difficulties to expect.

Comment: That's one for chat, certainly. Not only can you try out a few questions but you can see what a few years in one of those roles does to your state of mind. Our chat room isn't known as the mos eisley canteena of stack exchange for nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This absolutely would not meet the faq. To paraphrase a well known gameshow *They're only tough if you don't know the answer*.

From the [Don't Ask](https://serverfault.com/faq#dontask) section of the faq

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your question fails all of these tests it's not about a problem that *you* face. You are asking for a *list of things* which makes it chatty and open ended. All answers are equally valid and don't cotain an actual solution to a problem. If you read the rest of the don't ask section you'll see that it fails other tests in there too.

Comment: @lain so I suppose if I rephrased this question as a "problem I face",  e.g. I want to know if I am prepared to handle the tougher NOC problems, it's still too open-ended.

Comment: @T.Webster: You're right career style questions don't go down well on the main site. Chat here on SF or on security.stackexchange.com are better places to ask.